# Conversión correcta de item en ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, combobox, datagridview

Tengo un `ComboBox` que filtra un `DataGridView` según el ítem que se seleccione.

Con este método lleno el `ComboBox`:

```
public void llenarGenero(){
        try{
            cmbGenero.Items.Add("Seleccione");
            string conn = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT genero FROM clientesDos GROUP BY genero";
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read()){
                    cmbGenero.Items.Add(dr[0]).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Con este método realizo el filtro:

```
private void filtroGenero() {
        if (cmbGenero.SelectedIndex == 0) {
            llenarId();
        }else{
            try {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string conn = "cadena";
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)) {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string sSQL = "SELECT id, nombre, celular,url FROM clientesDos WHERE genero = @param";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Convert.ToString(cmbGenero.SelectedIndex));
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                dtgId.DataSource = dt;
            } catch (SqlException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y luego lo meto dentro del **Evento:**

```
private void cmbGenero_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
            filtroGenero();
        }
```

El problema es que al seleccionar un género del `ComboBox`, el `DataGridView` queda vacío. 
¿Alguna posible solución?

**Actualización:** la columna **GENERO** en la **Base de Datos** es de tipo **Varchar**

Comment: mea culpa.. no es selectedvalue el que buscas, es selecteditem.

Comment: tienes razón, diste en el clavo. Era SelectedItem. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carga el combo usando el `DataSource`

```
public void llenarGenero(){
    try
    {

        string conn = "cadena";
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string query = "SELECT genero FROM clientesDos GROUP BY genero";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cmbGenero.ValueMember = "genero";
            cmbGenero.DisplayMember = "genero";
            cmbGenero.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex){
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

entonces podras obtener el valor usando el `SelectedValue`

```
private void filtroGenero() 
{
    if (cmbGenero.SelectedIndex == 0) {
        llenarId();
        return;
    }

    try {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string conn = "cadena";
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(conn)) 
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string sSQL = "SELECT id, nombre, celular,url FROM clientesDos WHERE genero = @param";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Convert.ToString(cmbGenero.SelectedValue));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        dtgId.DataSource = dt;

    } catch (SqlException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

evalua como uso

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Convert.ToString(cmbGenero.SelectedValue));
```

para asignar el valor tomando la seleccion del combo

Comment: Me ha servido pero ahora no puedo visualizar un ítem. Es decir, previamente añadí al ComboBox el cmbGenero.ITems.Add("Seleccione") que es el item 0 para que si esta en 0 se cargue todo el DataGridView. Entonces, al no estar ese item el valor 'Femenino pasa a ser 0 y no filtra' . Esto se podría solucionar quitando el if pero quisiera una solución con el if

Comment: ese item adicional se lo puede agregar como row al datatable, despues de hacer el Fill() tienes que crear la row